# grep halts at files with no extension

Tags: grep

I am running a command to search certain string in a folder but it halts when it encounters file with no extension.

```
sudo grep -rlvF "peter.dickson@" /var/www
```

how I can overcome this?

As per the suggestion in the comment I have run this command

```
pawan@server1:~$ sudo find /var/www -type p
[sudo] password for pawan: 
pawan@server1:~$
```

But I didn't get any output from this command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. Extensions are completely irrelevant to `grep` (and 99.9% of all Linux programs) so that's not the problem. Are you sure it halts and isn't simply taking a long time? Can you reproduce it with a smaller file? The command you show will print _all_ lines of _all_ files in `/var/www` that don't match `peter.dickson@`. That could take ages if you have a deep directory tree with many, large files.

Comment: I am not sure but it halts at a specific location for hours, whereas that is a small file on check - `/var/www/lions322c2.org/run/motd`

Comment: how do you know it halts there? And, assuming it does, is that a regular file? Could it be a named pipe instead?

Comment: I am running the command as verbose - the screen continuously progress, but coming at this line `/var/www/lions322c2.org/run/motd` it just halts and there is no progress after that even for 14 hours. It is a normal file, I can paste the contents of the file if you want to have a look at it?

Comment: There is no "verbose" flag for `grep`. If you mean `-v`, that inverses the match and prints lines that _don't_ match the pattern, as I said in my previous comment. That said, if you see that file name, then that file has already been processed and your problem occurs with the next one. I am pretty sure that your issue is that you are grepping through a named pipe. That will hang indefinitely. Please [edit] your question and show the output of `find /var/www -type p`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you want is

```bsh
find /var/www -type f | xargs grep -l "peter\.dickson@"
```

The effect of xargs is that The outputs of find (all normal files under the path you provide) are passed as final arguments to the grep command (after the initial arguments provided).

Edit: the period is a special character for grep, so it should be escaped by preceding it with a backslash, as shown.

Comment: OP also used `v` and `F`. Also notice that `find` has a handy `-exec` switch which takes out the need and the risks of piping the output to another command: `find /var/www -type f -exec grep -lvF "peter.dickson@" {} +` (or if you really don't want to use `-exec`: `find /var/www -type f | xargs grep -lvF "peter.dickson@"`)

Comment: I assume that the OP wanted to do what he described in his question, that is, find lines matching the string, not lines *not* matching it. So -v is an error.  If you look up what -F does, you'll probably agree that it's not required here either.